# How to animate an external SVG file in an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I have a HTML file named `index.html` as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style>
        path {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
            stroke-width: 3;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg"></object>
    <img src="test.svg" />

    <p><button class="animate">Animate</button></p>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var button = document.querySelector('.animate');
            button.onclick = function (event) {
                var paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');
                for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
                    var path = paths[i];
                    var length = path.getTotalLength();
                    // Clear any previous transition
                    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
                    // Set up the starting positions
                    path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
                    path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
                    // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
                    // picks up the starting position before animating
                    path.getBoundingClientRect();
                    // Define our transition
                    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out ' + (2 * i) + 's';
                    // Go!
                    path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
                }
            };
        }());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and a SVG file named `test.svg` as follows.

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M52.25,14c0.25,2.28-0.52,3.59-1.8,5.62c-5.76,9.14-17.9,27-39.2,39.88" />

  <path d="M54.5,19.25c6.73,7.3,24.09,24.81,32.95,31.91c2.73,2.18,5.61,3.8,9.05,4.59" />

  <path d="M37.36,50.16c1.64,0.34,4.04,0.36,4.98,0.25c6.79-0.79,14.29-1.91,19.66-2.4c1.56-0.14,3.25-0.39,4.66,0" />

  <path d="M23,65.98c2.12,0.52,4.25,0.64,7.01,0.3c13.77-1.71,30.99-3.66,46.35-3.74c3.04-0.02,4.87,0.14,6.4,0.29" />

  <path d="M47.16,66.38c0.62,1.65-0.03,2.93-0.92,4.28c-5.17,7.8-8.02,11.38-14.99,18.84c-2.11,2.25-1.5,4.18,2,3.75c7.35-0.91,28.19-5.83,40.16-7.95" />

  <path d="M66.62,77.39c4.52,3.23,11,12.73,13.06,18.82" />

</svg>
```

## Question

I viewed `index.html` on Chrome but the animation does not work. Both files are in the same directory.

What is the proper way to animate the loaded SVG? As a note, I can animate when the SVG are copied and pasted to the HTML file as an inline SVG.

Comment: Your function runs as soon as it is loaded, but you need to wait on the SVG to load before running that function. I'd suggest using the `onLoad` attribute on the element to trigger the function.

Comment: Actually that might not be the issue, because you added an onclick event. I'll write an answer that should fix it

Comment: I've tried to replicate your issue, but no luck. Can you try creating a snippet or jsfiddle? As long as your file names are correct, it should load with no problems. Double check their location and file names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 documents (the html document and the object document) and you need to treat them as such. Styles from one document don't apply to the other so...

First we define the svg namespace and then move the path styles to the test.svg file so that becomes

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <style>
      path {
          fill: none;
          stroke: black;
          stroke-width: 3;
      }
  </style>

  <path d="M52.25,14c0.25,2.28-0.52,3.59-1.8,5.62c-5.76,9.14-17.9,27-39.2,39.88" />

  <path d="M54.5,19.25c6.73,7.3,24.09,24.81,32.95,31.91c2.73,2.18,5.61,3.8,9.05,4.59" />

  <path d="M37.36,50.16c1.64,0.34,4.04,0.36,4.98,0.25c6.79-0.79,14.29-1.91,19.66-2.4c1.56-0.14,3.25-0.39,4.66,0" />

  <path d="M23,65.98c2.12,0.52,4.25,0.64,7.01,0.3c13.77-1.71,30.99-3.66,46.35-3.74c3.04-0.02,4.87,0.14,6.4,0.29" />

  <path d="M47.16,66.38c0.62,1.65-0.03,2.93-0.92,4.28c-5.17,7.8-8.02,11.38-14.99,18.84c-2.11,2.25-1.5,4.18,2,3.75c7.35-0.91,28.19-5.83,40.16-7.95" />

  <path d="M66.62,77.39c4.52,3.23,11,12.73,13.06,18.82" />

</svg>
```

Then we need to change the animation code to extract the object's document. Note we cannot do this with an img element so I've removed that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg"></object>

    <p><button class="animate">Animate</button></p>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var button = document.querySelector('.animate');
            button.onclick = function (event) {
                var object = document.querySelector("object");
                var doc = object.contentDocument;
                var paths = doc.querySelectorAll('path');
                for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
                    var path = paths[i];
                    var length = path.getTotalLength();
                    // Clear any previous transition
                    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
                    // Set up the starting positions
                    path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
                    path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
                    // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
                    // picks up the starting position before animating
                    path.getBoundingClientRect();
                    // Define our transition
                    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out ' + (2 * i) + 's';
                    // Go!
                    path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
                }
            };
        }());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the svg works just fine, so as long as your file names + directory are correct, it should have no issue animating it.

```js
var paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');

var button = document.querySelector('.animate');
button.onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    var path = paths[i];
    var length = path.getTotalLength();
    // Clear any previous transition
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
    // Set up the starting positions
    path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
    // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
    // picks up the starting position before animating
    path.getBoundingClientRect();
    // Define our transition
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out ' + (2 * i) + 's';
    // Go!
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
  }
}
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
```

```html
<p><button class="animate">Animate</button></p>

<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M52.25,14c0.25,2.28-0.52,3.59-1.8,5.62c-5.76,9.14-17.9,27-39.2,39.88" />

  <path d="M54.5,19.25c6.73,7.3,24.09,24.81,32.95,31.91c2.73,2.18,5.61,3.8,9.05,4.59" />

  <path d="M37.36,50.16c1.64,0.34,4.04,0.36,4.98,0.25c6.79-0.79,14.29-1.91,19.66-2.4c1.56-0.14,3.25-0.39,4.66,0" />

  <path d="M23,65.98c2.12,0.52,4.25,0.64,7.01,0.3c13.77-1.71,30.99-3.66,46.35-3.74c3.04-0.02,4.87,0.14,6.4,0.29" />

  <path d="M47.16,66.38c0.62,1.65-0.03,2.93-0.92,4.28c-5.17,7.8-8.02,11.38-14.99,18.84c-2.11,2.25-1.5,4.18,2,3.75c7.35-0.91,28.19-5.83,40.16-7.95" />

  <path d="M66.62,77.39c4.52,3.23,11,12.73,13.06,18.82" />

</svg>
```